# Gamepad triggers main menu in Fuse SDL

Tags: emulation, zx-spectrum, joystick

I'm trying to set up a gamepad to work with Fuse on Ubuntu. No matter which type of joystick I try to emulate (including None), pressing button #2 (or B in the Sega naming) opens the main SDL menu. Looks like Fuse handles this button directly as even if this button is not mapped to any Fuse key, the menu still opens. It doesn't happen with GTK+.

If I map it to a key or some keyboard-based joystick type (Sinclair or Cursor), then pressing the button first opens the menu and second triggers the emulated key.

I tried two different 10 button joysticks, and both of them behave as above.

Is there a way to disable or re-configure this behavior?

Comment: Welcome to Retrocomputing. Strange emulator behaviour is annoying, but hopefully someone here will know how to fix it.

Comment: Fuse's main menu when using SDL is supposed to open on "F1", and *only* "F1". So, somehow, your controller must be set to somehow generate a key event "F1" when pressed.

Comment: It sounds reasonable but doesn't align with the following:

1. F1 is only triggered in Fuse SDL. I.e. pressing the button doesn't open help in apps like Nautilus or Chrome, but pressing F1 does.
2. Pressing the button twice opens and then closes the menu, while pressing F1 twice doesn't (it remains open).

Comment: Looks like it's hard-coded for Wii but somehow also triggers in my case: https://github.com/tom-seddon/fuse-emulator-code/blob/01922a6/fuse/input.c#L212-L214